# Как изменить цвет TabPageIndicator в стандартном стиле?

Tags: android, style, android-themes

Я использую `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 22
```

В этом стиле надо изменить толщину Индикатора и его цвет. Как это сделать с помощью стилей?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент у меня в стилях

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/BackgroundColorActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/BackgroundColorTabActionBar</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Вот либки

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать создать такой `style`:

```
<style name="MyTabWidgetStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/targetColor</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

и прикрутить его к `TabLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ...
    style="@style/MyTabWidgetStyle"
/>
```

Comment: Не помогло. Возможно я не совсем понял как прикручивать стиль

Comment: @Camel ну так показывайте как пробовали...какие либы подключены

Comment: Добавил данные в тело вопроса.

Comment: @Camel ну так вставляйте в свой стайл тот который я привел, и в разметке у TabLayout укажите этот стайл

Comment: Сделал, получаю такую ошибку `Error:(10, 22) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout'.`